# PROJECT EULER #29

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

Well, after solving this [problem](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=29) by naive STL set,I was reading the forum entries,there I find this entry :

```
 #include <iostream>   
 #include <cmath> 
 #define MAX 100
 using namespace std;

 int main(){
    int res=(MAX-1)*(MAX-1);
    for(int i=2;i<MAX;i++)
        for(int j=i*i;j<=MAX;j=j*i)
            res = res-int(MAX*(log(i)/log(j)))+1;
     cout<<res<<endl;
     return 0;
  }
```

**The author's explanation :**
`Maximum will be 99*99. I subtracted occurrences of those numbers which are powers of some lower numbers (2-100): -
For example: -
4^2,4^3,4^4 (i.e. 3 should be subtracted) as they will be duplicates from lower number powers as in 2^4,2^6,2^8`

This program is giving correct answer [check here](http://www.ideone.com/Kcuc2BGu) but I am unable to get the implemented logic,to be precise I am not getting **how the duplicates are determined.** Could somebody help ?

Comment: `static const int Max = 100;` would better. C++ programmers using `#define`'s for constants, tsk tsk.

Comment: That's not me I just quoted the author :P

Comment: This algorithm does not work.  Try MAX = 8 or 9.  For 8 it should give 44 but it gives 45.  For 9 it should give 54 but gives 56.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I may be missing something, but it seems to me this program gives the wrong answer. It's off by one. If I set `MAX` to 10, it's off by two.

I have read that some players like to produce approximate answers and then dictionary-attack the Project Euler servers to brute-force the problem. Other players consider that rather against the spirit of the thing.

Anyway—an algorithm like this (starting with N*M and eliminating duplicates) is the right way to tackle the problem, but as written this code doesn't make much sense to me. Note that in any case `int(MAX*(log(i)/log(j)))` is very sensitive to rounding error; but even if you eliminate that source of error by using integer arithmetic, the program still gives the wrong answer.

**EDIT:** How can we (correctly) count the duplicates?

First you must understand that two numbers are only the same if they have the same prime factorization. So there are only going to be duplicates *a*<sub>1</sub><sup>*b*<sub>1</sub></sup> = *a*<sub>2</sub><sup>*b*<sub>2</sub></sup> when *a*<sub>1</sub> and *a*<sub>2</sub> are distinct integer powers of the same integer, which I'll call *x*.  For example,

- 9<sup>7</sup> = 3<sup>14</sup>; this is possible because 9 and 3 are both powers of 3.
- 8<sup>6</sup> = 4<sup>9</sup>; this is possible because 8 and 4 are both powers of 2.

So we have established that for all duplicates, *a*<sub>1</sub> = *x*<sup>*e*<sub>1</sub></sup> and *a*<sub>2</sub> = *x*<sup>*e*<sub>2</sub></sup> for some integers *x*, *e*<sub>1</sub>, and *e*<sub>1</sub>.

Then with a little algebra,

> *a*<sub>1</sub><sup>*b*<sub>1</sub></sup> = *a*<sub>2</sub><sup>*b*<sub>2</sub></sup>
>
> *x*<sup>*e*<sub>1</sub>*b*<sub>1</sub></sup> = *x*<sup>*e*<sub>2</sub>*b*<sub>2</sub></sup>
>
> *e*<sub>1</sub>*b*<sub>1</sub> = *e*<sub>2</sub>*b*<sub>2</sub>

Going back to the earlier examples,

- 9<sup>7</sup> = 3<sup>14</sup> because 2×7 = 1×14.
- 8<sup>6</sup> = 4<sup>9</sup> because 3×6 = 2×9.

So to find all duplicates for any given *x*, you only need to find duplicates for the simpler expression *eb* where 2 ≤ *x*<sup>*e*</sup> ≤ 100 and 2 ≤ *b* ≤ 100.

Here is a picture of that simpler problem, for *x*=3 and *b* ranging only from 2 to 10.  I've marked two places where there are duplicates.

```
e=1  a=3    *********
e=2  a=9      * * * * * * * * *
e=3  a=27       *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *
e=4  a=81         *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *
                  |               |
        1*8 = 2*4 =  4*2         3*8 = 4*6
        3^8 = 9^4 = 81^2        27^8 = 81^6
```

And here are the duplicates:

```
e=1  a=3    *********
e=2  a=9      x x x x * * * * *
e=3  a=27       x  x  x  *  x  *  *  *  *
e=4  a=81         x   x   x   x   x   *   *   *   *
```

The C++ program you found is trying to count them by visiting each pair of overlapping rows i and j, and calculating how much of row i overlaps row j. But again, unless I'm missing something, the program seems hopelessly imprecise. And it misses some pairs of rows entirely (you never have i=9 and j=27, or i=27 and j=81).

Comment: Can you please explain how the duplicates are being computed ?

Comment: The code is giving correct answer, check this out : http://www.ideone.com/Kcuc2BGu

Comment: nthrgeek: It gives 9182 on my machine.  I've updated the post with a long explanation of what I think the program is trying to do and one reason why it's wrong.

Comment: If you eliminate the rounding error, it produces 9182, which is off by one. http://www.ideone.com/WSXVJEOD

Comment: I was struggling with this problem, trying to implement the same method, until I saw your explanation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are (at least) two ways to approach this problem.  One is to start your count of distinct values at 0, and add one for each calculated value that hasn't been seen before.  The other way is to calculate the maximum number of values, and then subtract one for each duplicate.

The poster is attempting the second methed.  `a` can range from 2 to 100 for 99 values, as can `b`, so there are 99 * 99 produced values.  The poster then attempts to subtract the duplicate values to get the correct answer.

Edit: However, the poster has written an incorrect algorithm.
For instance, setting `MAX = 8` or `9`. For `8` it should give `44` but it gives `45`. For `9` it should give `54` but gives `56`.  Either they lucked out and happened across an algorithm that gives the correct answer for some inputs, or they reverse-engineered an algorithm that worked when `MAX = 100` but not for all other values.

Answer (score 0):

first, it sets `res` to 99*99 at line 6, because `MAX` was defined as 100. Then it enters a loop, with the condition that i is smaller than `MAX`. then it enters this pseudocode loop

```
int i;
int j;
int x=2;
```

for( j = i<sup>2</sup>; j <= MAX , j = i<sup>x</sup>)
{
  res = res- (MAX* ( <sup>j</sup>log(i) )+1;
  x++;
}

sorry 'bout the not using `<pre><code>` above; but if I did I could not use `<sup>`

Please note `log(a)/log(x)` is the same as <sup>x</sup>log(a)

---

comments on question because `<sup>` does not work there:

<sup>2</sup>log(2) = 1  because 2<sup>1</sup> = 2
<sup>2</sup>log(4) = 2 because 2<sup>2</sup> = 2
log(x) == <sup>10</sup>log(x)
log(10) = 1

<sup>g</sup>log(x) = y => g<sup>y</sup> = x

Comment: the reverse of b^a. b is the ground. when left away, a ground of 10 is assumed: so 10log(10) will return one, because 10^1 = 10, and 2log(2) will return 1 because 2^1 = 2 and 2log(4) will return 2 because 2^2 = 4

Comment: sorry can't use html in comment section, so I can't superscript it

Comment: Ok I give up. I know what he's doing, but the why is over my head. sorry nthrgeek

Comment: Hey don't give up that easily .. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the question involves ways to combine two numbers chosen from a range. There are 99 possible numbers, so the number of combinations is 99 * 99, with possible duplicates. His basic algorithm here is to figure out how many duplicates are present, and subtract that value from the maximum.

As for counting duplicates, it might help intuitively to think of the numbers in terms of their prime factors. Raising a number to an integer power means multiplying it by itself; so, represented as a list of primes, this is equivalent to simply concatenating the lists. For instance, 6 is {2, 3}, so 6^3 would be {2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3}. Note that if you count how many times each prime appears in the list, x^n will always have *the same proportions* as x, for instance 6^n will have an equal quantity of 2's and 3's. So, any two numbers in the range with the same proportion between primes must both be powers of some number.

So, in the full list, each distinct proportion of prime factors will appear repeatedly as x^2, x^3, x^4..., (x^3)^2, (x^3)^4..., (x^4)^2..., etc., where x is the smallest number with that proportion; more precisely, (x^m)^n where (x^m) <= 100 and 2 <= n <= 100. Since (x^m)^n is equal to x^(m*n), counting duplicates amounts to counting the ways that x^(m*n) can also be <= 100.